# Google Sheet Script Editor - replace character for elements in a string

Tags: google-apps-script

I`m trying to replace a character in a string

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V1SNEL6kFzhBupx-Jtl0GTZDIaVXi-xE249xABR_Tfo/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to the sample data.

Basically, I'm trying to replace `_Placement` in the first column with ""
So that the results can be `Actual Name = ["platinum", "conquer", "Zebra"]`

Below is the script I tried to accomplish this task...

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < sheetsforremoval.length ; i ++) {
    if(sheetsforremoval.indexOf('_Placements') != -1) {
        sheetsforremoval[i] = sheetsforremoval[i].replace('_Placements', '""')
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with script?

The results of the above code gives me the below array

`["platinum", "conquer_Placement", "Zebra_Placement"]`

Only the first element was affected by the script.

Comment: Why are you checking indexOf on the whole variable instead of on sheetsforremoval[i]?

Comment: What do you mean whole variable?

Comment: `sheetsforremoval[i].indexOf` instead of `sheetsforremoval.indexOf` as you have above.

Comment: When I tried with sheetsforremoval[i].indexOf, it still returns the same results

Comment: @Jason1993 1. In your shared Spreadsheet, the values of column "A" are ``platinum_Placement, conquer_Placement, Zebra_Placement``. In your script, you find and replace ``_Placements``. ``_Placements`` is not included in the values of column "A" of the shared Spreadsheeet. 2. If the script is modified ``if(sheetsforremoval[i].indexOf('_Placement') != -1) sheetsforremoval[i] = sheetsforremoval[i].replace('_Placement', '""')``, ``platinum"", conquer"", Zebra""`` is returned. How about them?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, it`s you again!! I will give the above code try in a few hours. So we will get the desired results ["Platinum"", conquer"", Zebra""] by removing the for loop. But then how come using this for loop only affect the first element??

Comment: @Jason1993 If you want to replace only 1st element of ``sheetsforremoval``, please use ``sheetsforremoval[0] = sheetsforremoval[0].replace('_Placement', '""')``. By the way, do you want to replace the value with ``_Placements`` or ``_Placement``? And can you add your current script to your question? By this, users can think of about your solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643654/google-sheet-app-script-remove-tabs-automatically-if-tab-names-do-not-show-up

Comment: Hey Tanaike, I replicated this problem in this post

Comment: @Jason1993 If you found the answer for this question, please post it as an answer and accept it. By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry how do we post it as answer??

Comment: @Jason1993 You can see it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer